# Assigning session variable without saving to a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to set up something like a shopping cart, and what I have is a form to choose how many of each size shirt someone may want to buy.  I plan on having XXS, XS, S, M, L, XL, and XXL, and they choose a quantity of each and add it to the cart.  The simplest way I could think of doing this was to have a t.integer "size_??" for each size in a database for 'tshirt', and after the user clicks add to cart, that digit is then stored in the session until their payment is approved, in which case it is then saved to the database.  Then someone could view the database later to see what orders were placed.  (This would be for making custom shirts, so there would be no 'examples' saved on the database that need to be viewed or listed).

My first question is if that is correct.  I thought of using a "Shirts has_many Sizes" approach, but I'm not the most familiar with it, and if all I am trying to achieve is to obtain a quantity, I feel like that might be a little overkill.

My second question is this: if I have a form to select the quantity of each, how do I assign the values to the session variable.  My first thought was an approach like this:

```
new_order.html.erb:
<%=  form_for(:shirt, :url => {:action => 'save_to_session'}) do |f| %>
<table summary="New shirt order form">
<tr>    
    <th>Size S:</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%= f.select(:size_s, 0..99) %> </td>
</table>

  <%= submit_tag("Place order") %>

<% end %>
```

and on the controller side

```
  def new_order
    @temp_order = Shirt.new
    @temp_order.size_s = 0
  end

  def save_to_session
    session[:shirt_size_s] = @temp_order.size_s
    redirect_to(:action => 'show_session')
  end

  def show_session

  end
```

where show_session just spits out the session[:shirt_size_s]

The error Im getting with that is

> undefined method `size_22' for nil:NilClass

Perhaps this is taboo, as it seems to be a very simple approach, but this will not change the session value. If I add the following line to save_to_session it works, so I'm thinking perhaps save_to_session doesn't have access to @temp_order, but I'm still in the learning phase and don't exactly know what is going wrong here.

```
session[:shirt_size_s] = 12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your @temp is an instance variable normally used for populating the page and not used for retrieving data. You want to user the params[:field1] for that where field1 would be the name of your select.

Comment: Great, thanks! That worked, using session[:shirt_size_s] = params[:shirt][:size_s]